# Samsung refrigerator- ice maker works true only without container on ice

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker, samsung

In the Samsung RS68N8242SL refrigerator, the ice cubes from the ice maker only fall out if the container for ready ice cubes is removed. If we insert a container for cubes, they do not fall into the container by themselves. Check control button works correctly. Could you help us please?

Comment: Make sure your ice container is placed in the right way. Something is catching on the control arm. Are you using the correct container?

Comment: It would be helpful to add pictures of your ice maker with the container in place and also removed. Click EDIT on your question, then click the icon that looks like mountains to add a picture.

Comment: Yes, there is a bar that detects "bucket full" and shuts off the ice making.  Improper installation of the bucket (or wrong model of bucket) is causing that bar to rise and stop ice making.

Comment: Check for proper installation of the bar itself, too. The bar must be free to move up and down without obstruction or hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it's fixed. We had a lot of stuff in the freezer. When we loosened the vents it now works perfectly. The ice maker worked if the prepared ice cube tray was removed and air could flow. It is said to be a normal function. Ice maker will not release the cubes if there is no air flow in the freezer.